# AWS RDS unable to set public accessible attribute

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to connect mysql workbench to rds. I've created a database instance like so
[image]

However, I'm not sure how to make it publicly accessible. I've tried searching for answers on stackoverflow like this link =>
[AWS RDS public access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867896/aws-rds-public-access)
I'm using the default VPC security group and checked that it's connected to an internet gateway. And the dns hostnames and dns resolution seems to be enabled already. The public accessibility attribute is still 'no'. AWS no longer offers the option to toggle the public accessibility attribute it seems? I can't find it in the recent interface.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Would really appreciate your help! I have problems connecting to mysql workbench to rds, and I suspect it is this issue.

**What I tried and didn't work:**
I've tried vpc peering to create my custom vpc (in order to attach to an internet gateway), but it doesn't allow me to use the vpc as it's connected to only one subnet, and trying to connect it to another subnet fails as IPv4 CIDR overlaps/not in range for the second subnet. But I realised the default one is already attached to an internet gateway so this step was no longer neccessary.

Really need to get mysql workbench working on rds! Please help!

**Update:**
Found it, it's under connectivity

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AWS no longer offers the option to toggle the public accessibility attribute it seems? I can't find it in the recent interface.

You have to `Modify` your DB instance, then go to `Connectivity` and **expand** `Additional connectivity configuration`:

[image]

Then when you apply, choose `Apply immediately`.